# Could not write data in gemfire

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, oql

I am trying to write to gemfire server in region 'trade'.
My class is like :

```
public class TradeDetails{
String exchange;
String Product;
String Account;
String Quantity;
//getter and setter }
```

I have deployed the jar in the gfsh console.
The query I am running on gfsh console is

```
put --key=1 --value=('exchange':'xyz','Product':'abc','Account':'xyz','Quantity':'123L') --region=/trade --value-class=model.TradeDetails
```

But I am getting an error

> Couldn't convert JSON to Object of type class model.TradeDetails.

What could be the cause?

Comment: I think your JSON may be invalid. Could you try something like: `--value='{"exchange":"xyz",....}'`? Note in particular the enclosing `{...}` braces.

Comment: I tried put --key=1 --value={"exchange":"xyz","Product":"abc","Account":"xyz","Quantity":"123L"}' --region=/trade --value-class=model.TradeDetails
But it too didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the *GemFire* [documenation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/put.html), your *Gfsh* `put` command appears to be correct...

> put --key=1 --value=('exchange':'xyz','Product':'abc','Account':'xyz','Quantity':'123L') --region=/trade --value-class=model.TradeDetails

However, your `key` value `1` is a bit suspect. If you used a key constraint of `java.lang.Long` on your "/trade" *Region* then you also need to specify the `--key-class` option on the `put`.

I was able to successfully perform the following...

```
$ gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    v8.2.0

Monitor and Manage GemFire

gfsh>connect
Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=10334] ..
Connecting to Manager at [host=10.99.199.3, port=1099] ..
Successfully connected to: [host=10.99.199.3, port=1099]


gfsh>list members
Member Count : 1
Coordinator  : SpringGemFireDataServer (10.99.199.3(SpringGemFireDataServer:77179)<v0>:47312)

         Name           | Id
----------------------- | ----------------------------------------------------
SpringGemFireDataServer | 10.99.199.3(SpringGemFireDataServer:77179)<v0>:47312


gfsh>describe member --name=SpringGemFireDataServer
Name        : SpringGemFireDataServer
Id          : 10.99.199.3(SpringGemFireDataServer:77179)<v0>:47312
Host        : 10.99.199.3
Regions     : People
PID         : 77179
Groups      : 
Used Heap   : 229M
Max Heap    : 3641M
Working Dir : /Users/jblum/pivdev/spring-data-gemfire-tests-workspace/spring-data-gemfire-tests/target
Log file    : /Users/jblum/pivdev/spring-data-gemfire-tests-workspace/spring-data-gemfire-tests/target
Locators    : localhost[10334]

Cache Server Information
Server Bind              : localhost
Server Port              : 40404
Running                  : true
Client Connections       : 0


gfsh>list regions
List of regions
---------------
People


gfsh>describe region --name=/People
..........................................................
Name            : People
Data Policy     : partition
Hosting Members : SpringGemFireDataServer

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  | Name | Value
------ | ---- | -----
Region | size | 0


gfsh>
gfsh>put --region=/People --key=1 --key-class=java.lang.Long --value=('firstName':'Jon','lastName':'Doe') --value-class=org.spring.data.gemfire.app.beans.Person
Result      : true
Key Class   : java.lang.Long
Key         : 1
Value Class : org.spring.data.gemfire.app.beans.Person

Value
------
<NULL>

gfsh>
gfsh>describe region --name=/People
..........................................................
Name            : People
Data Policy     : partition
Hosting Members : SpringGemFireDataServer

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  | Name | Value
------ | ---- | -----
Region | size | 1
```

Note, my "/People" *Region* has a key type of `java.lang.Long` and value type of [`org.spring.data.gemfire.app.beans.Person`](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/beans/Person.java).

Although, when I attempted to read "Jon Doe" back out, *Gfsh* puked...

```
gfsh>get --region=/People --key=1 --key-class=java.lang.Long --value-class=org.spring.data.gemfire.app.beans.Person
Exception occurred. null
```

However, I did go onto create a [(Spring Boot-based) GemFire client cache application](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireDataClient.java) (with a [base configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireDataClient.java#L43) of [SpringGemFireClient](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireClient.java)) that [pulled the Person back out](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireDataClient.java#L56) successfully.

```
Person is [Jon Doe]
```

You might try annotating your `model.TradeDetails` application domain type with the Jackson mapping annotations, though I am not certain *Gfsh* actually uses them to perform the mapping since I think (when I lasted checked) *Gfsh* was not using Jackson.  But, it wouldn't hurt either.  Either way.

Note, my Server was started with this [SpringGemFireDataServer](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireDataServer.java), which is based on [SpringGemFireServer](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/app/main/SpringGemFireServer.java).

Hope this helps (a little :-).

Cheers!
John

Comment: Just a quick update... I modified my example and configured the "/People" Region with (PDX) read-serialized set to true as well as used Jackson's mapping annotations in my application domain model type (org.spring.data.gemfire.app.beans.Person).  Neither modification made a difference and I still encounter the "Exception occurred. null" error in Gfsh.  However, the Spring Boot-based cache client application continues to access the person (Jon Doe) in the "/People" Region on the server just fine.

Comment: And yet, another quick update... as further proof that the data/person (Jon Doe) does exist, I am able to query (with OQL) the person in Gfsh like so...  
gfsh>query --query="SELECT * FROM /People WHERE lastName = 'Doe'"

Result     : true
startCount : 0
endCount   : 20
Rows       : 1

 name   | firstName | lastName
------- | --------- | --------
Jon Doe | Jon       | Doe

NEXT_STEP_NAME : END

Comment: It still doesnt work after adding --key-class=java.lang.Long

Comment: Basically what I wanted to do is add a Table 'TradeDetails' with columns exchange,Product,Account,Quantity. But what I understood is that we can add only in form of map(key,value). Is there any way to add table data in cache

Comment: GemFire is a Key/Value store, so NO.  But, essentially, you can have a strongly-typed Region (i.e. Region tied to a specific application domain object type, e.g. TradeDetails).  The properties (exchange, product, account, quantity, etc) of TradeDetails can be indexed and used as a predicate in an OQL (query) statement like any column in a RDBMS.  If yor data is serialized as PDX, it is also a simple matter to add/remove properties (columns).  However, GemFire is not a true columnar store like, say Cassandra.